# Memory fault - c

Tags: c, linux

I do not know why I get Memory fault (core dumped) when I run this code

```
if (flg == 4) // PIPE
   {

     char **cmds;
     char ***cmdarg;
     int j=0;

     cmds = split_str(cmd, "|");

     for (i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++)
     {
      if (strcmp(args[i], "|") == 1)
         {
          cmdarg[j][i]=args[i];
         }
      else
         {
          cmdarg[j][i+1] = NULL;
          j++;
         }
       printf("%s\n",cmdarg[j][i]);
     }
   }
```

I am not so expert with pointers and arrays

Comment: what does `split_str` return? what is `args`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the C Shell. Removed it from the title.

Comment: And where does it crash ? Did you run it with a debugger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmdarg` is not initialized. And I'm sure that GCC, when invoked as `gcc -Wall -g`, would have warned you about that.

You could keep its length, e.g.

```
int cmdarglen = 0;
```

Then initialize it to some suitable default size:

```
#define INITIAL_CMDARG_SIZE 10
cmdarg = calloc(INITIAL_CMDARG_SIZE, sizeof(*cmdarg));
if (!cmdarg) { perror("calloc cmdarg initial"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);  );
cmdarglen = INITIAL_CMDARG_SIZE;
```

then grow it when needed, e.g.

```
if (j >= cmdarglen) {
   int newcmdarglen = 5*j/4+10;
   char***newcmdarg = calloc(newcmdarglen, sizeof(*cmdarg));
   if (!newcmdarg) 
      { perror("calloc growing cmdarg"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   memcpy (newcmdarg, cmdarg, sizeof(*cmdarg)*j);
   free (cmdarg);
   cmdarg = newcmdarg;
}
```

to be inserted appropriately inside your `for` loop. Of course, you probably need to initialize each element of `cmdarg` (by allocating them individually).

Don't forget to `free(cmdarg)` later.

At last, [learn](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) how to **use the `gdb` debugger** and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) memory leak detector.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the `cmdarg` variable in you code. It will have an unspecified value, so when you dereference it, there is undefined behavior. In your case, this manifest by a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your code is trying to do, but what I can see is that you are reffering to an **uninitialized variable** 'cmdarg'.

Another adivce: when possible (and I think that nearly always it is possible) try to avoid three levels of indirections (***).

Comment: You initialize it by allocation. For example: `cmdarg = new char**[<size>];` Later you will have to allocate for each cell. i.e. each pointer-to-pointer (**) item in this array. Again - I would try to avoid such high levels of indirections.

Comment: @PazO: `new` is for C++, and the OP is talking about C